# Form not showing in form view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I made a form using form wizard (using two tables all with records in them).

The form looks good in design view but only shows header in form view and no fields. I have read through the suggested answers and seems to have settings correct.

Comment: If you are using two tables what joins are you using?

Comment: It seems like there are no records to display..aka Your record source for the form is either incorrect or you literally have no data to show, and the form property "Allow Additions" is set to No. If you know VBA you can use something like `Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "No records"
    End If
End Sub`